# "Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method" error when creating class

Tags: android

I created a new `class` on Android Studio:

```
package com.apress.gerber.contentprovider;

import android.content.ContentProvider;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by BBC on 2017/9/21.
 */
public class BookProvider extends  ContentProvider{

}
```

For `public class BookProvider extends  ContentProvider` there is an error message:

> Class 'BookProvider' must either be declared abstract or implement
>   abstract method 'getType(Uri) in 'ContentProvider'

How to fix it?

Comment: There are 6 methods you need to override, this article might help you https://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/

Comment: "_How to fix it?_" Either declare the class as abstract, or implement all the abstract methods from the parent.

Answer (score 1):

> How to fix it?

First, you rethink whether you really want to create a `ContentProvider`. Few apps need a custom-written `ContentProvider` — either they do not need a provider at all or can use pre-written ones such as `FileProvider`.

Then, if you really want to go ahead with this, you need to follow the instructions in the error message, and implement the `getType()` method on your `BookProvider`. You will then get more error messages for other methods defined as `abstract` on `ContentProvider`, such as `onCreate()`, `query()`, `insert()`, `update()`, and `delete()`. You will need to implement all of those as well. Exactly *how* you implement them is up to you, based on the business logic of this `ContentProvider`.

You can learn more about implementing a `ContentProvider` in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), along with books and training on Android app development.